# UIsearchbar Getting No Response when Requesting for Website

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uisearchbar

I am trying to send an address to the search bar, but nothing happens:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {  

if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com"){ 

        let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url) 

        Webview.loadRequest(requestObj)
    }
    SearchBar.text = "http://" 
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchbar: UISearchBar) {

    searchbar.resignFirstResponder()

    let text = SearchBar.text

let url = NSURL(string: text!)

    let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url! as URL)

    Webview.loadRequest(urlRequest)   
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: im trying to get my search bar to work when type an address

Answer (score 0):

Your searchBar delegate got a wrong function signature.

```
 func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar){
// func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchbar: UISearchBar) {
```

so your search is not working